# Select the minimum value for each row join by another table with condition on some fields

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have 2 table such:

```
       UserTelTable                        (userTable)        
CardNo  ID   tel     telorder            ID    Name     .....(other columns )
1      101   7777       4                101   Danny     
2      101   6666       1                102   Tanya     
3      101   5555       2                103   Susan     
4      102   4444       6                104   Gordon    
5      103   1234       1                  
6      104   4567       2                  
7      104   5678       3                 
8      101   4141       6                
9      101   5151       3                  
10     102   0000       3                 
11     102   1111       5                
12     104    7890      4                
13     104    1212      1
```

want the result to be like this:

```
Name   .....some columns of UserTAble   tel# TELPriorinty(Minimum)
Danny    .................                   5555    
Tanya    ...................                 0000
Susan     ................                   1234
Gordon     ...............                   1212
```

where the result showing the minimum value of "telorder" for each "userid",username,userfamily,.. and filtered by the date selected.

Comment: Filtered by the date. Where is the date field?

Comment: but danny has min `telorder` 1 (the second row) with tel 6666

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: It's unclear what you want to filter by, and exactly what you want the min of. You say in the description you want the minimum of telorder but in your example it appears to be the minimum of tel. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a mistake in the first row of the expected result. Use the subquery with `group by` to find the lowest `telorder` in `UserTelTable` and then appropriately join the tables.

```
select ut.*, utt.*
from userTable ut
join UserTelTable utt on ut.id = utt.id
join 
(
  select id, min(telorder) min_telorder
  from UserTelTable
  group by id
) t on utt.id = t.id and
       utt.telorder = t.min_telorder
```

Answer (score 1):

You could join the linked  table with the a subquery on min value

```
  select a.name, b.tel
  from userTable a
  inner join UserTelTable b on a.id =b.id 
  inner join (

  select ID, min(telorder) telord
  from UserTelTable
  group by ID
  ) t on t.id =a.id and t.telord = b.telorder
```